# rolling exponentially weighted mean and standard deviation

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like the below

```
 date             A           B             C
 2000-01-31     0.03          0.05         0.07
 2000-02-28     0.04          0.06         0.08
```

I would like to get the 60 month rolling exponentially weighted mean and standard deviation with a minimum window of 12. I am not sure how to do this using rolling function and ewm. thanks for your help